# Why is this scope's lambda followed by a block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Here is [a method described in the Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope):

```
scope(name, body, &block)
```

This is an example of using that method also described in the Rails API:

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') } do
    def dom_id
      'red_shirts'
    end
  end
end
```

The question is about the following code:

```
do
  def dom_id
    'red_shirts'
  end
end
```

What does it stand for? I can't find any Ruby syntax about a block could follow a lambda. Did I miss something? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: a lambda is an object just like any other object. There is no difference between `-> { where(color: 'red') }` and `42`. Now, have you seen methods that take both positional arguments and a block? E.g. `respond_with` in Rails? Well, there's no difference between that and `scope`.

Comment: This confused because two points. 1. It is `look like` connect with lambda,not scope . 2, the third optional proc params make it more delusive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the lambda is the second regular argument to `scope` and the block is the block argument to `scope` (not related to the lambda syntax).

[The block lets you define what ActiveRecord calls "extensions"](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope), methods that can be called on the return value of the association. The method defined in your example would be called like this:

```
Shirt.red.dom_id
```

[`has_many` associations can be extended in the same way.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) This example is a little weird since it has to do with the view layer; extensions are more often used for things like finders and creators.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, got it.

Answer (score 1):

dom_id id a method of the scope, you can calle Shirt.red.dom_id but you can't call Shirt.dom_id. Some times you need methods that only belong to a given scope

Comment: I've known  the scope meaning ,but I don't understand  this block after lambda.is there somewhere mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the problem.

```
def testLambdaParams(name,body)
  puts name
  body.call
  yield "testLambdaParams_yield" if block_given?
end

second_proc = -> do
  puts "second_proc"
  yield 'second_proc' if block_given?
end


testLambdaParams "first_params",second_proc do |x| 
  puts "block exec for testLambdaParams " + x
end
```

The result:

```
first_params
second_proc
block exec for testLambdaParams testLambdaParams_yield
```

The last block is for `testLambdaParams`,**NOT** for *lambda*.